# Print the outcome of a dice game

Tags: java, eclipse

I have to make a dice game for a class.

I have to print out how many wins and loses the user got at the end.

This is my code so far and it works for the game itself.

I just don't know how to finish off the end.

Also, it keeps printing off the same numbers for each round and I'm not sure how to fix it so it prints random numbers for each round.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program06
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner stdln = new Scanner(System.in);
        int d1 = (int)(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
        int d2 = (int)(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
        int d3 = (int)(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
        int o1 = (int)(Math.min(d1, Math.min(d2, d3)));
        int o2 = 0;
        int o3 = (int)(Math.max(d1, Math.max(d2, d3)));
        int y = 0;

        if (o1 != d1 && o3 != d1)
        {
            o2 = d1;
        }

        System.out.println("Roll your dice.");
        System.out.println("Roll a triple and you win.");
        System.out.println("Roll a straight and you win.");
        System.out.println("Roll any pair of 7s or higher and you win.");
        System.out.println("Roll any pair of 6s or lower and you lose.");
        System.out.println("Roll anything else and you lose.");

        do
        {
            System.out.print(+d1);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print(+d2);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(+d3);


            if (d1 == d2 && d2 == d3)
            {
                System.out.println("You won!");
            }
            if (d1 >= 7 && d2 >= 7 || d1 >= 7 && d3 >= 7 || d2 >= 7 && d3 >= 7)
            {
                if (d1 == d2 || d2 == d3 || d1 == d3)
                {
                    System.out.println("You won!");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("You lose.");
                }
            if (o1 < o2 && o2 < o3 && o3 > o1)
            {
                System.out.print("You won!");
            }
            if (o2 < o1 && o3 < o2 && o1 > o3)
            {
                System.out.print("You won!");
            }
            if (o1 > o2 && o2 > o3 && o3 < o1)
            {
                System.out.print("You won!");
            }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("You lose.");
            }
            System.out.print("Would you like to play again? Enter 1 for yes, 2 for no: ");
            y = stdln.nextInt();


        } while (y == 1);
        if (y == 2)
        {
            System.out.print("You played );
        }
        stdln.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Every time the player wins, increment a variable by 1, then print the value of that variable at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Before your loop, declare 2 variables `int winCount = 0; int loseCount = 0;`

Each time you print "You won!" you should add a statement `winCount++` (this will increment the counter each time someone wins). Similarly, in the places where you print "You lose." you should add `loseCount++`

Your final print statement should be `System.out.print("You played " + winCount+loseCount + " games! You won " + winCount + " of them and lost " + loseCount + " of them.");`

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you! Now I'm running into the problem where it keeps printing out the same numbers for each round. How do I fix that?